# Glossaries-extra package and amsart breaking title of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart, glossaries-extra

I am working with overleaf, and the following code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Sample}

\end{document}
```

will give the following output:

[image]

The title "Contents" of the table of contents appears below the actual table of contents. Is there any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `\glsxtrRevertMarks` or `\glsxtrRevertTocMarks` in your preamble.